# Problem with the roots of polynomial given by sum of geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, roots, matlab

Let's say I want to distribute leaflets for 60 months and in total I want to distribute $2500000$ leaflets. In my first month I want to distribute $8000$ leaflets and then I want to increase my speed of distribution every month at the same rate to finally reach $2500000$ at month 60.

Essentially I think I want this equation (1):
$$8000+8000x+8000x^2+...8000x^{59}=2.50\cdot10^6$$
We can rewrite it as
$$8000[1+x+x^2+...+x^{59}]=2.5\cdot10^6$$
Hence
$$1+x+x^2+...x^{59}=312.5$$
I have a geometric series with $a_1$=1 and I need to find r. Hence
$$312.5=\frac{1\cdot(1-x^{60})}{1-x}$$
Which gives the polynomial (2):
$$x^{60}-312.5x+311.5=0$$
I plug into matlab and get a bunch of complex roots and two real roots which are:

```
1.046923161434767 + 0.000000000000000i
1.000000000000000 + 0.000000000000000i
```

I double check that the first root works in excel (Buncf or rows hidden) and it works HAPPY DAYS:
[image]

**QUESTION**
I undersrtand that $x=1$ is a root of the polynomial (2), but clearly it does not satisfy my initial equation (1). Why did the equation for the sum of finite geometric series allow this thing? If I were to use any of the remaining 58 complex roots, would it give me 2.5 million?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You multiplied by $1-x$ when you converted the fractional equation to a polynomial equation.  Then a root $1-x=0, x=1$ comes from this multiplying factor and not your original equation.

Had you stayed with the original geometric series sum, which had degree $59$ instead of $60$, there would not have been this extra multiplying factor and all of the roots would be good, except for the fact that distributing a complex number of leaflets might be a little challenging to implement.  Then again, entering the long polynomial into the computer is less challenging but still not attractive.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the sum of a finite geometric series is not valid when the common ratio $x$ is $1$.  Indeed, it is derived by dividing by $1-x$, which is not possible if $x=1$  So, the equation $$312.5=\frac{1\cdot(1-x^{60})}{1-x}$$ is only equivalent to your original equation (1) assuming that $x\neq 1$.  Under that assumption, you can then reversibly multiply both sides by $1-x$ to find that equation (2) is equivalent.

So, equations (1) and (2) are equivalent assuming $x\neq 1$.  This means that the solutions to equation (2) besides $x\neq 1$ are all solutions to equation (1), and $x=1$ may or may not also be a solution to equation (1) (and in this case it is not).

More generally, the lesson here is that solving an equation is not just a matter of doing manipulations to reach an answer.  It is crucial to understand the *logic* behind these manipulations, since you are really making an argument that certain equations *imply* other equations under certain assumptions.  The directionality of the implications and the assumptions needed make all the difference.